# send_keys is failing with phantomJS

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, phantomjs

Selenium `send_keys()` method is not working while using phantomJS, even though it is working without using phantomJS.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
password = wait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']")))
password.send_keys("pass1")
```

Comment: What is the exception>

Comment: Could you please add the next couple lines of your script? (after `password.send_keys("pass1")`)

Comment: @demouser123  this is the exception lines: -->                                                
 File "E:\Selenium\gen_Login.py", line 35, in Login_func
    wait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='password']"))).send_keys("pass1")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were pretty close. As per the documentation you need to use the in-built [**WebDriverWait()**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) method in-conjunction with `expected_conditions` as `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control#password"))).send_keys("pass1")
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='password']"))).send_keys("pass1")
  ```

Comment: Same error :/     File "E:\Selenium\gen_Login.py", line 35, in Login_func
    wait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @id='password']"))).send_keys("pass1")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I am using webdriverwait as wait  like in the start of code. from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait